# Trouble in Disabling Second Level Cache in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jboss, second-level-cache

I have used ehcache in my application. I deploy my application in jbossAS7 server. I want to disable second level cache now. I have removed the cache properties from my hibernate configuration file, deleted my ehcache.xml file, removed the cache usage from all the hbm files. When I deploy my project in jboss, I can see that the second level cache is enabled.

[org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] (MSC service thread 1-6) Second-level cache: enabled

How do I disable it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this 
sessionFactory.getCache().evict(..);
and else you can follow this link, which will explain you everything and tell you how to do it

http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/08/evict-collection-from-hibernate-second.html

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem. Posting the answer here for anyone who reaches this thread.

In your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, set the following property to `false`

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

**Note**: commenting out this property will throw an application error if there are still annotations in your class files (or `<cache>` tags in hbm xml files)